# Add item to a new list of strings

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I have a function with input params: Number and list of strings, e.g: (1, ListString)

And i need it to return a new list of strings that looks like:

```
[["1","name1"], ["1","name2"]]
```

For each string in my input string list, i need to place it in that structure, so i've build the following:

```
def buildStringForproductsByCatView(tenantId:String, cat:List[String]):List[String]=
{
  var tempList= List[String]()//(cat.foreach(x => "[[\"1\",\""+x+"\"]]"))
  cat.foreach(x => println(("[[\"1\",\""+x+"\"]]")))
  cat.foreach(x => tempList + ("[[\"1\",\""+x+"\"]]"))
  println(tempList.mkString(","))
  tempList
}
```

The list does not fill with items, i tried several ways, but could not get it.

The print line works fine, i am getting this:

```
[["1","1"]]
[["1","cat1"]]
```

I just want to add them to a new list of string..

Answer (score 2):

There are two wrong things in your code.

First one, to append an item to List you should use `:+`. `+` is not what you are looking for. `tempList + "asd"` implicitly converts the list to a String and appends the text to this string. This might be confusing.

The second one, `List` is immutable, so each `:+` call returns you a new List.

So your code should look like this:

```
x => tempList = tempList :+ ("[[\"1\",\""+x+"\"]]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Although two other answers are technically right, I fail to understand why you don't use map:

```
def buildString4ProductsByCatView(tenantId:String, cat:List[String]) = {
  cat.foreach(x => println(("[[\"1\",\""+x+"\"]]")))
  cat.map(x => "[[\"1\",\"" + x + "\"]]")
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is -> I am new to scala.. :) !

Comment: Then, take a look at [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) feature, and triple quotes -- it might save you from excessive use of escaping and make that string a bit readable (although it's a matter of taste in your case): `s"""[["1" , "$x"]]"""`

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use ListBuffer[String] with append and finally toList:

```
def buildStringForproductsByCatView(tenantId:String, cat:List[String]):List[String]=
{
  cat.foreach(x => println(("[[\"1\",\""+x+"\"]]")))
  val langItems = ListBuffer[String]()
  cat.foreach(x => langItems.append(("[[\"1\",\""+x+"\"]]")))
  langItems.toList
}
```